# Given a SignalR ConnectionId, can I tell whether that session is still connected?

Tags: signalr

For a variety of reasons, when a SignalR connection is established, I'm storing that ConnectionId in my datastore. However, those connection records can get orphaned, for instance, if SignalR restarts. (I've also observed behavior that makes me wonder if OnDisconnected() is getting called correctly, though I'm less sure of this.)

But for whatever reason, I periodically end up with records in my database that are orphaned, and I'd like to be able to prune those, and remove any ConnectionID listed that isn't actually connected anymore - presumably by having SignalR tell me whether this ConnectionID is still associated with a live session.

I've looked through the SignalR source, and it's not leaping out at me how best to accomplish this. Is there a reasonable way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is to track clients on your own.  From your post it seems like you are already doing this (still provided code in case you aren't) but this is the only way to know if a client is connected.  The SignalR server triggers the onconnected/ondisconnected events in as a way of indicating if a client is or is not connected.

I'd recommend ensuring that your not re-instantiating records in your database on reconnect incorrectly.

For instance (super simple example):

```
class myHub
{
    private static List<String> _connectedClients = new List<String>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        _connectedClients.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        _connectedClients.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public static bool IsConnected(string cid)
    {
        return _connectedClients.Contains(cid);
    }
}
```

You can now call IsConnected on the hub to determine if a connection ID is currently connected.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Maybe 98% of the time it does, but every now and again, I'll close all my browsers on my dev machine, and then when I go back into my room, it'll be convinced that there's still something in my version of `_connectedClients`, even though everything should have been cleared. I don't have a repro for it, though, so that's not much help for you guys. I'll let you know if I can figure out what triggers it - or if (maybe more likely) it's a bug on my side.

Comment: @N. Taylor Mullen why your last void return bool value??

Comment: @aliyouhannaei no reason, just a fail code snippet. Just updated it.

Comment: @N. Taylor Mullen that's just for fun ;) can i call this method in javascript? i want to check destination id before send new message, or any way to send message before close chat?

Comment: If you change the IsConnected to be non-static you will be able to call it from JS.  Once the application has been closed, the connection also closes and therefore is unable to receive any further messages.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me also, from time to time I detect an orphaned connection.

As a work around, I added a client side function, $(window).unload which invokes a server side function that does what disconnect is supposed to do..

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Storing connectionId in DB isn't the good way. SignalR will assign a new id for each page. Try this [sample of Kevin W. Griffin](http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/)